# How to catch flutter app crash on Startup

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

i need to catch app crash log, this app crash happen when running/debug at AndroidStudio on startup (still not yet a signed apk). i have tried using [sentry](https://github.com/flutter/sentry), but i does not catch any error.

i have tried to test print text at try-catch on `main.dart` but sentry cant catch it.

any better idea ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Faced same problem, in Android Studio you can see all device logs if you haven't selected specific debug application. then you can easily identify why your app is crashing.

1. Open LogCat ( not flutter terminal)
2. Select your device
3. Leave debugable process as empty
4. Then launch your application and check log